# What are the openid connect endpoint api for paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, openid-connect

I have tried few openid connect end points, but none of them seems working. For example, I tried For getting an authorization code:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize
```

For the token:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/tokenservice
```

I have also tried these, without success:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/authorize
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting back?  And what do you expect to get back? Can you link to the relevant documentation in addition to showing exactly what code or command-line commands you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/identity/?mark=openid
For example:

```html
curl -v --insecure https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -d "client_id=<Client-Id>" -d "client_secret=<Secret>" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "code=<Authorization-Code>"
```

Comment: What is the endpoint for getting authorize code? I can use above endpoint only when I have auth code.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/#obtain-users-consent), the authorize URI for the sandbox is:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize
```